# Ruby linalg library undefined symbol _gfortran_concat_string

Tags: ruby, linker, fortran, gfortran, lapack

I followed these instructions for installing the linalg library (along with LAPACK & f2c): https://www.quora.com/Installation-Instructions/How-do-I-install-Ruby-linalg-library-on-Mac

For those not on quora, I've been taking notes on installation instructions:
http://pastebin.com/QbvE5MJc

I had linalg successfully working on one machine, but now am trying it on another and it isn't working. Everything works up until I actually try to use it in ruby.

```
ldubinets@lm16 ~/Code/lapack/linalg $ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'linalg'
LoadError: /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/lapack.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_concat_string - /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/lapack.so
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/linalg.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

My machine is running Linux Mint 16. Just installed a fresh install.

I've read on the internet that I have to link gfortran in a makefile somewhere with -lgfortran 
http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2957

There was a Makefile in linalg/ext/linalg and linalg/ext/lapack that had this line

```
 LIBS = $(LIBRUBYARG_SHARED) -llapack -lblas -lpthread ...
```

to which I added "-lgfortran" and reinstalled, but it didn't help at all.

How do I link to gfortran in this installation?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Well, since the error is thrown by lapack.so, it seems that I need to link gfortran during installation of lapack. Is this so? 
Elsewhere on the internet people say that this may be caused by conflicting fortran compilers (g77 & gfortran), though I don't have g77 installed so I don't know how that can be the case.

Comment: Did you copy the binary or did you make a new build on the new machine?

Comment: I built lapack & blas on the new machine using the instructions at the first pastebin link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, this line in each of the Makefiles was the culprit:

```
LIBS = $(LIBRUBYARG_SHARED) -llapack -lblas -lpthread ...
```

Adding `-lgfortran` to this line makes everything work, but with one caveat. When you run `sudo ruby install.rb` it regenerates the Makefiles. Therefore what I did to fix the problem was this:

```
sudo ruby install.rb config  # generates the makefiles
sudo vim ext/linalg/Makefile # add -lgfortran to that line
sudo vim ext/linalg/Makefile # add -lgfortran to that line
sudo vim install.rb          # find the method config in the Main module and comment out everything inside it (so it won't regenerate the config)
sudo ruby install.rb         # does the entire install process, but does't regenerate the config.
```

This is a super hacky method of fixing it, but it works. If anybody has a better way please let me know!